# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2',

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyside2

The am using docker container ubuntu 18.04, I have installed python 3.7. The program works on ubuntu 18.04 with GUI.

`pip -version` or `pip3 -version`

Output: `pip 22.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

I am facin the following error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2'`

I have tried installing it by running:
`pip install PySide2`
But this is the error I get:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2
```

I have also tried:
`pip3 install PySide2`
But still get the same error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2
```

I was initally using python 3.8. But read somewhere that it does not suppose it. So I installed python 3.7. I have got the same error with python 3.6 and python 3.5

I have also adding `--user`, that is,
`pip install PySide2 --user` and `pip3 install PySide2 --user`
I still continue to get the same error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2
```

I have also tired `sudo apt-get install PySide2`
Then I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package PySide2
```

I even tired installing the wheel directly from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4)

and then run it. It doesn't work.

I would really apprecite if someone can help me out here!

Comment: As far as I can see on the [project homepage](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/), Python versions from 3.5 to 3.10 ought to be supported.

Comment: Show us the output of these commands `pip --version` and `pip3 --version`

Comment: To add to John's comment above, if you have multiple Python versions installed, `python3.x -m pip` may be a better option.

Comment: @JohnGordon `pip --version` gives me this 
`pip 22.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: @Rahul I do not have multiple python versions installed. It's only Python 3.7. I built the containers with other python versions but none of them worked. As of now I only have python 3.7. No other python version.

Comment: Try `python3.7 -m pip install PySide2`. Or try reinstalling it.